# big number is not correct in C though it can be represented correctly in 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Tags: c

Here is my code.

```
// Fibonacci function in C
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int fib(int n);

unsigned long long int main()
{
    unsigned long long int n,result;
    printf("Enter n for a_n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    result=fib(n);
    printf("a_%d is %d",n,result);
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long int fib(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(n==2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

When I input 48, the output is 512,559,680.
But in python is 4,807,526,976.
I think unsigned long long enough is enough to denote the output.

Comment: The compiler should be giving some warnings about your usage of the `%d` format when printing an `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &n);` - you realize `n` is `unsigned long long`, right? that's not the proper format specifier for `scanf` to extract such a thing from stdin. You should also be getting a warning about `fib(n)` whence you're passing something-not-`int` to a function expecting `int`. Short version: turn up your warnings to pedantic levels and consider them ALL as errors, then fix them; don't ignore or hide them.

Comment: BTW, [`fib(48) == 4,807,526,976`](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html), not 4,294,967,295

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks. Sorry for the typo. I have corrected it to right value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is correct, but you're printing only part of it because of the `%d` format here:

```
printf("a_%d is %d",n,result);
                ^^ here
```

The correct result is 4807526976, or 0x11e8d0a40 in hex. You got 512559680, or 0x1e8d0a40 in hex. Compare them side-by-side:

```
correct: 0x011e8d0a40
you got: 0x001e8d0a40
```

That is, you printed the last 4 bytes of the value because the `%d` format interpreted the number as a regular integer, which is 4 bytes wide on your machine.

To fix this, turn on all compiler warnings and see what format it suggests instead of `%d` (likely `%llu`).

---

User input is inherently dynamic, and format strings (like `"a_%d is %d"`) are just strings, so a statically-typed language (like C or OCaml) can't determine whether some format specifier (like `%d`) is wrong - as in, the specifier says `signed int`, but the (static!) type of the variable you're printing is `unsigned long long int`. As a result, I think that formatting using format strings is doomed from the beginning because static type-checking silently becomes dynamic, provided by the machinery inside `printf`, and you lose all guarantees of static type-checking.

It looks like the only way to solve this is to insert a "hack" in the compiler that would type-check format strings. That's how your C compiler with all warnings enabled is able to spot the mistakes:

```
test.c:8:16: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type
      'unsigned long long *' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%d",&n);
           ~~  ^~
           %lld
test.c:9:25: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'unsigned long long' [-Wformat]
    printf("a_%d is %d",n,result);
              ~~        ^
              %llu
test.c:9:27: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'unsigned long long' [-Wformat]
    printf("a_%d is %d",n,result);
                    ~~    ^~~~~~
                    %llu
```

Similarly, in OCaml, [`Printf.printf`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html) has this weird type:

```ml
val printf : ('a, out_channel, unit) format -> 'a
```

...even though in your code it's called with a format string:

```ml
Printf.printf "a_%d is %d" 4 (fib 4)
```

Similarly, in Rust, there's this weird type [`std::fmt::Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html), which represents the format string and can't be constructed at runtime. So, this type is actually used for formatting, yet in code you write format strings:

```rust
println!("a_{} = {}", 48, 0x11e8d0a40u64)
```

Comment: my compiler is `mingw64`. How can I do the hack to get warnings?

Comment: @kile, the "hack" is already there. You should just enable all warnings with the `-Wall` option, or something like that. It's not really a hack, it's more of a feature of the compiler - I'm calling it like this because, as far as I understand, plain C shouldn't even be able to catch such mistakes in format strings because they're just strings, and their content is not type-checked.